# Is a Boeing Honeywell ‘Uninterruptible’ Autopilot System pre-installed on any in-service airliners?

Tags: aviation

Some sites make the claim that Boeing has installed an uninteruptible ground-controlled autopilot in aircraft such as the 777 with registration 9M-MRO used for missing flight MH370.

Notable claims (that this system is already installed and could have been misused):

- [Boeing’s ‘Uninterruptible Autopilot System’, Drones & Remote Hijacking](http://21stcenturywire.com/2014/08/07/flight-control-boeings-uninterruptible-autopilot-system-drones-remote-hijacking/) - 21stCenturyWire.com

Related references:

- [Boeing HoneyWell Uninterruptible Autopilot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Honeywell_Uninterruptible_Autopilot) - Wikipedia.
- [System and method for automatically controlling a path of travel of a vehicle](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US7142971) - Google Patents
- [Boeing patents anti-terrorism auto-land system for hijacked airliners](http://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/diagrams-boeing-patents-anti-terrorism-auto-land-system-for-hijacked-210869/)
- [New Autopilot will make another 911 impossible](http://www.standard.co.uk/news/new-autopilot-will-make-another-911-impossible-7239651.html)

Boeing's patent was registered in 2003, so dates after the 2001 9-11 attacks. But also after the 2002 delivery date of the 777 registered as [9M-MRO](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b777-28420.htm) which was used for flight MH370.

Is there any evidence that any Boeing aircraft are, or have been, fitted with this sort of system prior to delivery to airlines?